# Svelte - Export a variable but Rollup reports that the variable isn't exported

Tags: variables, import, export, svelte, rollupjs

I'm new to svelte (3 weeks) and don't know if I'm doing something wrong. Trying to export a const to use in another component, the vscode doesn't report any error, but the rollupJs in the cmd report this error:

```
[!] Error: 'repos' is not exported by src\components\Request.svelte, imported by src\components\List.svelte
```

But the variable is been exported just fine (I guess).

this is the Request.svelte:

```
<script>
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
let userName = ''
export const repos = writable ([]);
```

and this is the List.svelte when I want to import the const repos:

```
<script>
import {onMount} from "svelte";
import {MDCList} from '@material/list';
import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple';
import {repos} from './Request.svelte'

repos = data;
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expose a variable for imperative use somewhere else, you need to export it from the module script:

```html
<script context="module">
  import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
  export const repos = writable ([]);
</script>

<script>
  ..
</script>
```

Tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports

However, I see that in your code snippet you do `repos = data`. This doesn't work, you can't change an exported property like that from the outside. If you want to declaratively change a component property (not a module property) from the outside, you do `export let repos = ..` (note the `let` instead of `const`) and then do `<List repos={data} />` in the component where you use it. Tutorial on props: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props

Comment: Thanks for all the tips man. Now that you said I see the the mistakes, thanks a lot.